# How can I remove only selected items from LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I remove only selected items from LocalStorage?

I created a button to cancel the task. But when I click on it all other tasks are deleted.

```js
const tasks = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", addTask);

function createLi(value) {
  tasks.push(value);

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
  container.appendChild(li);

  let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = "\u00D7";
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);

  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);
}

// ADD A TASK
function addTask() {
  createLi(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

function deleteTask() {
  localStorage.removeItem("task");
}

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task")).forEach((task) => {
  createLi(task);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="btn">SEND</button>
<ul id="container">

</ul>
```

Comment: Create a deep copy of original object, update it, and set new value to local storage. To remove something alltogether, just use `removeItem()`  / `localStorage.clear();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage stores key-value pairs in a Storage object, so when you call `setItem()`, it's akin to updating the key-value pair with key = `task`. Think of it like:

```
localStorage = { "task": "[task1, task2, task3, ...]" }
```

But when you call `removeItem()`, it removes the entire key-value pair from LocalStorage, so when you later call `localStorage.getItem("task")`, it's going to return a null value.

What your `deleteTask()` function needs to do is still call `setItem()`, but update the tasks array written to LocalStorage, so it doesn't contain the task you're deleting. Something like:

```
function deleteTask(taskToDelete) {
  const tasks = localStorage.getItem("task");
  const updatedTasks = task.filter(task => task != taskToDelete);
  localStorage.setItem("task", updatedTasks);
}
```

You still want a value returned in `localStorage.getItem("task")`, but the returned value is changing depending on which tasks have been added or removed.