# How to selectively remove items from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"><button>add</button> <button class="delete">delete all items</button>
    <div class="todo"></div>




    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo');
const dtbn = document.querySelector('.delete')
var taskList;
var localdata = localStorage.getItem('localItem');
var localItems = JSON.parse(localdata);


btn.onclick = () => {
  if (localItems === null) {
    taskList = [];
  } else {
    taskList = localItems;
  }
  taskList.push(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem('localItem', JSON.stringify(taskList));
  input.value = "";
  ShowList();

}

const a = (element) => {
  localStorage.removeItem('')
}

const ShowList = () => {
  let outPut = "";
  if (localItems === null) {
    taskList = [];
  } else {
    taskList = localItems;
  }
  taskList.forEach(element => {
    outPut += `<li>${element}<button onclick=${a(element)}>delete</button></li>`
  });
  todo.innerHTML = outPut
}
ShowList();

dtbn.onclick = function () {

  localStorage.clear();
}
```

I want to make a simple to do list. Here, when we write to the input, we add it and it is added to the list. But I want each list item to be deleted when the delete button is clicked. How can I do this?
I want it to be removed from both the list and localStorage.

Comment: `window.localStorage.clear();`

Comment: i want to delete single items, not all localStorage

Comment: your task list is being saved as one object in localStorage, not as individual items. So every time the list is modified, you resave the entire list. It's not a big dead.

Comment: you may delete it using key, 

there are several tutorial regarding this topic.You may check following links to study and for better understanding.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0YQBdpOv5A
https://thecodingpie.medium.com/how-to-build-a-todo-list-app-with-javascript-and-local-storage-a884f4ea3ec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove only selected items from LocalStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612517/how-can-i-remove-only-selected-items-from-localstorage). In the future please search [S0] before asking a question. There are currently many that already asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+item+from+localStorage%3F

Answer (score -1):

```
localStorage.removeItem("yourkeyName");
```

Thats can be work.

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question. Also Pasha is already using `localStorage.removeItem`.